# Gremlin merge two traversals

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have 2 traversals: 1 to find vertex by label and another to find edges by label and I'm trying to merge them i.e. get all **edgeLabel** edges for vertices with **vertexlabel** label.

vertex traversal:

```
graph.traversal().V().hasLabel("vertexLabel")
```

edges traversal function (must be a different function):

```
private GraphTraversal<Vertex, Edge> getEdges() {
    return __.inE("edgeLabel");
}
```

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
graph.traversal().V().hasLabel("vertexLabel").and(getEdges())
```

Comment: I'm curious why you are wanting to inject traversals into the query rather than just parameterize the query itself? Is you example perhaps just a simple case of something more complex you are looking to build?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `and` or `filter` (depending on the specific `Traversal` you are traversing)

```
TinkerGraph g = TinkerGraph.open();

/*
         u:A
<1:A> ---------- <2:B>
  |                |
  | x:B            | v:B
  |                |
<4:B> ---------- <3:A>
         w:A
*/

Vertex v1 = g.addVertex(T.label, "A", T.id, 1);
Vertex v2 = g.addVertex(T.label, "B", T.id, 2);
Vertex v3 = g.addVertex(T.label, "A", T.id, 3);
Vertex v4 = g.addVertex(T.label, "B", T.id, 4);

v1.addEdge("A", v2, T.id, "u");
v2.addEdge("B", v3, T.id, "v");
v3.addEdge("A", v4, T.id, "w");
v4.addEdge("B", v1, T.id, "x");

// predefined traversal from somewhere
Traversal<Vertex, Vertex> vertexFilter = __.hasLabel("A");
Traversal<Vertex, Vertex> edgeFilter = __.hasLabel("B");
Traversal<Vertex, Edge> vertex2edges = __.bothE().filter(edgeFilter);
Traversal<Edge, Vertex> edge2vertex = __.bothV().filter(vertexFilter);

System.out.println("Get edges matching filter with any vertex matching filter:");
g.traversal().E().filter(edgeFilter).and(edge2vertex).toList()
        .forEach(e -> System.out.printf(" - %s%n", e.id()));

System.out.println("Get vertex matching filter with any edge matching filter:");
g.traversal().V().filter(vertexFilter).and(vertex2edges).toList()
        .forEach(v -> System.out.printf(" - %s%n", v.id()));
```

with output

```
Get edges matching filter with any vertex matching filter:
 - v
 - x
Get vertex matching filter with any edge matching filter:
 - 1
 - 3
```

Comment: thank you but this is not an answer to the question. need to combine 2 traversals so in your case extract the .bothE("edgeLabel") to a different function

Comment: Oh excuse me, then simply put the traversal inside a combinator (`filter`, `and`, `map`, ...). I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

emm Gremlin dsl is really hard to use in some case..I take hours to find out the solution.

the way is to use admin to split a Traversal into steps and add to a another ,here is the code

```
  //split the input e.g __.inE("edgeLabel") into steps;
  List<Step> steps = graphTraversal.asAdmin().getSteps();
  //get the inner admin
  GraphTraversal.Admin admin = graph.traversal().V().asAdmin();
  //append step to admin
  for(Step step : steps) {
    admin =  admin.addStep(step);
  }
  //get the result
  admin.next()
```